# Highlight highest nth values in each table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following table, I am wanting to add a class to the top 5 values in each row, only of the TD's with the class of 'championshipPoints'. After some searching and trial and error, I have managed to get the class added to the highest value, but I am struggling to get any further.

If the 6th and 7th values are the same I only want one of them highlighted.
I would like to try and solve on my own but could do with a pointer or 2 to start me off.

Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
<table id="2020societyChampionship">
    <tbody>
     <tr class='memberPoints'>
        <td>1</td>
        <td class='playerName' scope='row'>player1</td>
        <td class='championshipPoints'>6</td>
        <td class='championshipPoints'>20</td>
        <td class='championshipPoints'>7</td>
        <td class='championshipPoints'>13</td>
        <td class='championshipPoints'>0</td>
        <td class='championshipPoints'>20</td>
        <td class='championshipPoints'>25</td>
        <td class='championshipPoints'>0</td>
        <td class='championshipPoints'>11</td>
        <td class='championshipPoints'>11</td>
        <td class='championshipPoints'>0</td>
        <td>100</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class='memberPoints'>
        <td>1</td>
        <td class='playerName' scope='row'>player2</td>
        <td class='championshipPoints'>25</td>
        <td class='championshipPoints'>20</td>
        <td class='championshipPoints'>8</td>
        <td class='championshipPoints'>11</td>
        <td class='championshipPoints'>0</td>
        <td class='championshipPoints'>16</td>
        <td class='championshipPoints'>22</td>
        <td class='championshipPoints'>0</td>
        <td class='championshipPoints'>11</td>
        <td class='championshipPoints'>11</td>
        <td class='championshipPoints'>0</td>
        <td>100</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
```

**JQ**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('tbody tr').each(function() {

     var $tds = $(this).find('.championshipPoints');
     var values = $tds.map(function(){return parseFloat($(this).text());}).get();

       $tds.eq(values.reduce((iMax, x, i, arr) => x > arr[iMax] ? i : iMax, 
        0)).addClass('highestFive');
  });  
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jonpho/okw8qm0s/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sort()` and [`slice()`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/)

```js
$('tbody tr').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.championshipPoints').sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.innerText - a.innerText;
  }).slice(0, 5).addClass('highestFive')
});
```

```css
.highestFive {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="2020societyChampionship">
  <tbody>
    <tr class='memberPoints'>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class='playerName' scope='row'>player1</td>
      <td class='championshipPoints'>6</td>
      <td class='championshipPoints'>20</td>
      <td class='championshipPoints'>7</td>
      <td class='championshipPoints'>13</td>
      <td class='championshipPoints'>0</td>
      <td class='championshipPoints'>20</td>
      <td class='championshipPoints'>25</td>
      <td class='championshipPoints'>0</td>
      <td class='championshipPoints'>11</td>
      <td class='championshipPoints'>11</td>
      <td class='championshipPoints'>0</td>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='memberPoints'>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class='playerName' scope='row'>player2</td>
      <td class='championshipPoints'>25</td>
      <td class='championshipPoints'>20</td>
      <td class='championshipPoints'>8</td>
      <td class='championshipPoints'>11</td>
      <td class='championshipPoints'>0</td>
      <td class='championshipPoints'>16</td>
      <td class='championshipPoints'>22</td>
      <td class='championshipPoints'>0</td>
      <td class='championshipPoints'>11</td>
      <td class='championshipPoints'>11</td>
      <td class='championshipPoints'>0</td>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close. I've made [this js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4r07aox/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tbody tr').each(function() {

    var $tds = $(this).find('.championshipPoints');
    var values = $tds.map(function() {
      return parseFloat($(this).text());
    }).get();
    values.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    console.log(values);

    const highlightAbove = values[values.length - 5];
    $tds.each(function() {
      var val = parseFloat($(this).text());
      if (val >= highlightAbove) $(this).addClass('h')
    })
  });
});
```

I get the values, sort the values, get the 5th largest number, and then iterate over the tables and highlight the ones >= the 5th largest number by adding a class.

Comment: Thank you that works well....almost, in the fiddle 2nd row all three '11's ' are highlighted, how can I get just 1 highlighted?

Comment: Well Jon, that's up to you